# Steps for Export and Import in Liferay

Tags: export, liferay, publish

I have built a website in Liferay using eclipse IDE.

Please tell me the step by step procedure for export/import or publishing website from development machine to deployment machine. .

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two options available to you:

1) Backup your development database & restore it on your production database (make sure all additional portlets are deployed on the production box as well).

2) use Liferay's export / import functionality found

- Go to Control Panel
- Go to the community you want to export
- Click actions -> Manage Pages
- Go to Export / Import
- Select all options for Export
- Save the resulting LAR file somewhere convient
- Upload the LAR file to your production server
- Follow the previous steps but go into Import
- Select any options you require
- Click "Import"
- Voila, you're done!

Comment: thanks a lot ... i followed these steps as you said.... i am able to export and the import the website..<br> But the main problem i am facing is when i restart the server or restart the machine , the Community gets removed .

Comment: The Community gets removed?! That's a strange issue. What database are you using? i.e. MySQL, Hypersonic etc? Is all data being removed or just this Community? Glad I could help with your previous question though!

Comment: Where is this setting in Liferay 6.2?

Comment: It's under Control panel > Site Pages (In the sidebar) > Export button (it's at the top of the page).

Answer (score 2):

For the record in Liferay 6.1 the export in control panel under "site pages".